# jenkins - plugin (credentials) install manually

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to setup `jenkins` version 1.651.3 with manual installation of `credentials` plugin.

But failed to install the plugin.
Here is what I tried;

1. Download `jenkins` from `http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_1.651.3_all.deb`.
2. Install `jenkins_1.651.3_all.deb` on `Ubuntu 16.04`.
3. I can see the default `credentials` plugin version is `1.18`.
4. Delete old files; `rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/credentials*`.
5. Download latest credentials plugin from `https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/credentials/2.1.13/credentials.hpi`.
6. Restart jenkins; `service jenkins restart`.
7. Still the credentials version is `1.18` not `2.1.13`.

How can I install the latest `credentials` plugin manually? I mean without accessing web UI (Manage Jenkins -> Manage plugins)?

Comment: I also installed latest `structs` plugin. But it does not helped. :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the doc describing this behavior; plugin pinning.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=46334825#content/view/46334825

After creating xxx.jpi.pinned it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins creates a directory named after the plugin for every .hpi file you have in your $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/.

Try to find that directory (name should be **'credentials'**) and **delete it**.

Comment: I did it as step 4. But still same problem.